# Using cursors with mysqldb and flask

Tags: python, mysql, flask

It's more of a theoratical question but i have been trying to find a correct answer of it for hours and yet i have't arrived at a solution. I have a big flask app and it contains multiple routes.

```
@app.route('/try'):
@app.route('/new'):
```

and many others. I am using MySQLdb for database purpose. Before i was having this in the starting of the application.

```
import MySQLdb as mysql
db = mysql.connect('localhost', 'root', 'password', 'db')
cursor = db.cursor()
```

It works fine but after a time, it generates a error "Local Variable 'cursor' referenced before assignment.". This may be due to the reason that after a time mysql closes a connection. So, i entered 
cursor=db.cursor() in every route function and close it afer i have done the processing like this:

```
db = mysql.connect('localhost', 'root', 'password', 'db')
@app.route('/')
def home():
    cursor=db.cursor()
    ...some processing...
    cursor.close()
    return render_template('home.html')
@app.route('/new')
def home_new():
    cursor=db.cursor()
    ...some processing...
    cursor.close()
    return render_template('homenew.html')
```

Now i want to ask is this approach right? Should i define a cursor for each request and close it?

Comment: Flask's tutorial might probably help: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/tutorial/dbcon/

Comment: wrt/ your "Local Variable 'cursor' referenced before assignment.", the connection being closed would not generate this kind of exception, and it's very very likely a programming error like rebinding `cursor` in a function after it has been used. BUT: you **want** to keep your cursor local to your functions anyway, else you will have some serious troubles as soon as you have more than one client at a time.

Comment: @sebastian I still don't get it. How am i supposed to use get_db(). I should call that in every function and that would be same as doing cursor=db.cursor().

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers so using defining a local cursor in each function would solve the issue and closing it in the end. Right?

Comment: @AarushiIgn Yep - take a minute and switch to steps 4 & 5 of the tutorial and you'll get examples for that as well.

Comment: Yes. FWIW, you may even have to open more than one single cursor in a function if you have overlapping queries (like issuing some update statements while iterating over the results of a select statement).

Comment: @sebastian Okay yeah correct so advantage of using get_db() would be that if there is a connection open, it will use that one instead of creating another one?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I do happen to have multiple select statements in some functions, so is there a need to have separate cursors for each query execution?

Comment: Depends on 1./ if they are overlapping, and 2./ if you iterate directly on the cursor (ie : ` for row in cursor: do_something_with(row)`) or use `cursor.fetchall()` to retrieve your rows (which might not be a good idea on huge dataset) before you issue another query. As far as I'm concerned, I use direct iteration over the cursor (unless I retrieve one single row or it's not a select query) and one cursor per query (unless there's no overlapping queries, but even then you easily get burned when refactoring your code).

Comment: All i am doing is this `cursor.execute('SELECT Id,Name FROM abc ORDER BY RAND() limit 9 offset 0;')
data = list(cursor.fetchall())`. and then 2-3 times this again. They are not overlapping, thought i don't know what you actually mean it by overlapping here as they are all select statement, no insert or update. But they all of them query to a single table in one function. Like select this and then select that from table abc

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Does opening once cursor per query doesn't have any time or speed issues or anything like that? I don't want it to be slow.

Comment: `list(cursor.fetchall())` is mostly useless (unless you have some postprocessing to do on your resultset, and even then...) - `fetchall()` returns a tuple or list (depending on your database). wrt/ "speed issues", there's of course a small overhead opening / closing cursors but that's really small (a quick test using timeit gives roughly a 0.9 factor in execution time using the same cursor 3 times vs using 3 different cursors - tested with MySQLdb, so YMMV). If you're concerned about such a difference, you should certainly avoid `ORDER BY RAND` ;)

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I am using `ORDER BY RAND` in 1-2 statements only and yes i will remove it(good tip). So instead of using `cursor.fetchall()` what else should i use? I need to store the data fetched by the query so that i can pass it to the template or do some processing on it.

Comment: Dépends on your templating system and the required processing but if you are using something like Jinja then you can just pass the cursors to the template and write filters or tags to take care of the processing. Else, well, you're stuck with `fetchall()` indeed.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers well then no worries, i'm using jinja :)

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers and thank you for solving my queries and everything!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I have my MySQLdb setup

```
def requestConnection():
"Create new connection. Return connection."

    convt = cv.conversions.copy()
    convt[3] = int
    convt  

    conn = db.connect(host=c.SQL_HOST, port=c.SQL_PORT, user=c.SQL_USER, passwd=c.SQL_PASSWD, db=c.SQL_DB, conv=convt, use_unicode=True, charset="utf8")
    return conn

def requestCursor(conn):
    return conn.cursor(db.cursors.DictCursor)
```

Then, at the start of every SQL function I do this:

```
def executeQuery(query):
    "Execute a given query. Used for debug purpouses."

    conn = requestConnection()
    cur = requestCursor(conn)

    cur.execute(query)

    r = cur.fetchall()

    cur.close()
    conn.close()

    return r
```

I change conversions because I had to change int values in DB from Float to int due to my work, but you can skip this step.

If not, you need to import this:

```
import MySQLdb as db # https://github.com/farcepest/MySQLdb1
import MySQLdb.converters as cv
```

Hope it helps!